# What does "gcc -xW" do?

Tags: gcc, clang, icc

What is the effect of "-xW" flag?
I see this sometimes provided to gcc/icc in the linking phase. clang breaks on this, saying:

```
clang: error: language not recognized: 'W'
```

Example usage: http://www.spec.org/cpu2000/results/res2004q1/cpu2000-20040208-02830.cfg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ICC option only:

```
     -xW  --  Can  generate SSE2 and SSE instructions, and it can
     optimize for Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 processors  and  Intel(R)
     Xeon(R)  processors  with SSE2. This is the default on Linux
     systems using Intel(R) 64 architecture.  This option is  the
     same as specifying -march=pentium4.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an option for the Intel C compiler, not for gcc - see here:

http://www.rcac.purdue.edu/userinfo/resources/common/compile/compilers/intel/man/icc.txt

> -xW  --  Can  generate SSE2 and SSE instructions, and it can optimize 
>   for Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 processors  and  Intel(R) Xeon(R)  processors
>   with SSE2. This is the default on Linux systems using Intel(R) 64
>   architecture.  This option is  the same as specifying -march=pentium4.